# c# Getting error while try to read receiving email from gmail

Tags: c#, gmail-imap

Im trying to read receiving email from gmail and I did it.
If emails receive one by one it works perfectly.But if emails receive three or four at the same time.I miss at least two of them.
I hope describe my issue properly.
Here is my code for reading;

```
private void StartReceiving()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, txtEmail.Text, txtSifre.Text, AuthMethod.Login, true))
            {
                if (client.Supports("IDLE") == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("server crash");
                    return;
                }
                client.NewMessage += new EventHandler<IdleMessageEventArgs>(OnNewMessage);
                while (true) ;
            }
        });
    }
    static void OnNewMessage(object sender,IdleMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("mesaj geldi");
        MailMessage m = e.Client.GetMessage(e.MessageUID, FetchOptions.Normal);
        f.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            f.txtGelen.AppendText("Body: " + m.Body + "\n");
            
        });
        
    }
```

What should I do ? Im kinda newbie at this,i have to read at least 4 emails at same time.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with gmail, but I had a similar problem when I was reading a TCP/IP log file, and it kept sending messages while I was processing.

The way I resolved it was to use a LIST of strings, and then process it in a background worker. Changing a string in place could be an issue in a race situation.

This is cut and pasted out of my code, and modified without checking my syntax, but it goes something like this:

```
    private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorkerReadMail;
    private List<string> messagesToBeRead = null;

    /****************************************************************
     * readPassedMessage(string str)
     * Puts message in queue, and calls background worker 
     ****************************************************************/
    private void readPassedMessage(string str)
    {
        string stringToRead = str;

        if (messagesToBeRead == null) messagesToBeRead = new List<string>();
        messagesToBeRead.Add(stringToRead);
        if (backgroundWorkerReadMail != null && backgroundWorkerReadMail.IsBusy == false)
        {
            backgroundWorkerReadMail.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else if (backgroundWorkerReadMail == null)
        {
            // need to create it
        }
    }

   private void backgroundWorkerReadMail_DoWork(object passedObj, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

            if (messagesToBeRead == null || messagesToBeRead.Count == 0) return;
            if (backgroundWorkerReadMail.CancellationPending)
            {
                messagesToBeRead.Clear();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bool messagesLeftToRead = true;
                while (messagesLeftToRead)
                {
                    string curString = messagesToBeRead[0];

                // < ADD CODE HERE TO DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH YOUR MESSAGE > //
                    
                    messagesToBeRead.RemoveAt(0);
                    if (messagesToBeRead.Count == 0 || backgroundWorkerVoiceAssist.CancellationPending)
                        break;
                }  // while (messagesLeftToRead) end brace
            }
    }
```

Comment: Oh many thanks,i will try backgroundworker things.You light me up really thx.